# lerv - what month is that in English?

Tags: перевод

lerv - what month is that in English? Also the months of Pros - unora - cerv - kvei 
The people on the tombstones were born in Russia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about Russian language

Answer (score 4):

This is Czech. `prosinec` is December, `únor` is February and `květen` is May; *červ-* is tricky as it could be either `červen` "June" or `červenec` "July". What you see as "lerv" could be a corruption of *červ-* (there will be two of these in any case, and I'm not aware of any consistent system in Czech for disambiguating the two); alternatively though much less likely, it's `leden`, January.